# Flask blueprints with SQLAlchemy for APIs -- what can I do to simplify?

Tags: python, rest, flask, sqlalchemy

I am designing an app that has a database, a CRUD web interface to manage its content, and exposing a REST API to be called by an external UI written in React. I am using native Flask Blueprints, SQLAlchemy, along with Marshmallow for API serialization.

The way I have structured Blueprints, based on what I learned from the Flask docs, seems unnecessarily complicated:

- `app.py` -> `__init__.py`.`create_app()` registers blueprints

  - "factory" Flask pattern
  - each blueprint imports from a `routes` module
  - `register_blueprint` specifies two blueprints one for HTML, another for API as each has a different `url_prefix`
- each `routes` module `__init__.py`

  - imports Blueprint, then
  - creates the blueprint instances for html and api, then
  - imports the actual routes for the module (e.g. `from routes.user import routes`)
- each `routes` implementation

  - imports the blueprints created in the module
  - imports the SQLAlchemy model and Marshmallow schema
  - creates the code for the routes, and decorates with the correct blueprint depending on HTML or API
- each model imports required elements for SQLAlchemy

So the SQLAlchemy approach seems just right: in one place I define all the characteristics of the model and thus the associated database tables, as well as the schema for JSON output of my API.

But the Blueprints approach seems convoluted, with dependencies scattered about -- to define one new route, I typically have to modify three files:

- `app` module (`__init.py__`)
- `routes` module for the specific route (`routes/user/__init.py__`)
- `routes` implementation for the specific route (`routes/user/routes.py`)
- and each of these implicitly depend on the model for the entity (e.g. `user`)

All of this is functional, but I am assuming there's a simpler way to approach the problem that I have not yet fully grasped. Is there a simpler, cleaner way to implement this?

Comment: you can check [flask-cookiecutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter-flask/cookiecutter-flask/tree/master) approach to deal with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can follow approach as in [flask-cookiecutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter-flask/cookiecutter-flask/tree/master)

in `app.py` you can create app as

```
def create_app(config_object="{{cookiecutter.app_name}}.settings"):
    """Create application factory, as explained here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appfactories/.

    :param config_object: The configuration object to use.
    """
    app = Flask(__name__.split(".")[0])
    app.config.from_object(config_object)
  
    register_blueprints(app)
 
    return app
```

and you can create blueprints in any `routes.py` or ``views.py file in project
and then register them (add them to app) in the register_blueprint function as

```
def register_blueprints(app):
    """Register Flask blueprints."""
    app.register_blueprint(public.views.blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(user.views.blueprint)
    return None
```

this will eliminate the need to add routes to `routes/__init__.py` file each time you create views in different routes for different use case.

Comment: Perfect answer! Cookiecutter is the pattern of top-shelf Python that I have been looking to learn and emulate.  Thank you.